# Creating an icon widget with all icon import

Tags: flutter

Hello I am new to flutter and learning, My question is how can I create a widget for icon where I
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLKZc.png)can call all the libraries and then then use the Icon in other .dart file,
I have done the same thing in React Native and want to achieve the same functionality in flutter as well

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lW0EK.png)

Answer (score 0):

As per the Widget you have built, I do no think you need to define the `customIcon` list.

In your `CustomIcon` widget, simply pass the `IconData` in the `type`.

Example

```
import "package:flutter_feather_icons/flutter_feather_icons.dart";
CustomIcon(type: FeatherIcons.github)
```

If you want to use your `customIcon` so that you do not have to import the packages again, you could do

```
CustomIcon(type: customIcon.FeatherIcons.github)
```

Comment: I have added all the imports in CustomIcon file, so I dont have to import any icon package into my current file, for Example I am using 4 Icons from 4 different packages, so I made customIcon widget and imported all the packages there so I dont have to import into my current file, I have done same thing in React Native, but unfortunately I am not able to achieve this functionality into flutter